# Next.js - Serverless rendering with Clouflare Workers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, cloudflare-workers

I'm using Next.js v9 and would like to take advantage of Next's serverless deployment option by using my application with Cloudflare Workers.

From the Next.js docs, I know that every serverless function created by Next has the following signature:

```
export function render(req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) => void
```

When using Node's `http.Server` class (using `express` for example), passing in the `req` and `res` object becomes trivial and there is an example shown in the docs of doing this.

However, the issue is that Cloudflare Workers use a different `Request` and `Response` object than Next expects. The docs for their `Request` object can be found [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/request/) and the docs for their `Response` object can be found [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/response/).

So while a simple "hello world" app running on Cloudflare Workers looks like this:

```
// 1. Register a FetchEvent listener that sends a custom
//    response for the given request.
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

// 2. Return a custom request object
async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response('hello world')
}
```

and rendering a simple Next.js function might look something like this:

```
const page = require('./.next/serverless/pages/some_page.js');

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  return page.render(request, new Response());
}
```

there is an inherent mismatch between the resuest and response types so I suspect errors will be thrown.

I know that I need to modify these so that they're passed in as Next.js expects. I know that the Worker's `Request` object can be modified as seen [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/templates/snippets/modify_req_props/). But I'm unsure of how exactly to make it match with the `http.IncomingMessage` object. And I'm not sure on how to format the `Response` object either. Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: This will be complicated. `ReadableStream`s and NodeJS `Readable`s are completely different internally.  The list goes on with other implementations. So filling the gap here will be a lot of work. I guess its way easier to rework the routing ...

Comment: Yeah it looks that way. But could clarify what you mean by "rework the routing"?

Comment: Well, don't use NextJS.

Answer (score 6):

What you're aiming to do is replicate the API for the [Node.js `http` module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) which provides [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) and [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). That seems like a monumental undertaking that, in some ways, defeats the purpose of working with Cloudflare Workers which are modeled on the Service Worker API. Instead, consider dropping Next.js for a Cloudflare Workers-specific approach to SSR for React, as Cloudflare demonstrates [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/serverless-pwa-react-cloudflare-workers/).

Comment: I see, thanks for the head's up and the link. Do you think it would be possible to use Next in the traditional way - i.e. without specifying the build target as serverless - with Cloudflare? Having to write the application using the bare-bones `renderToString` approach defeats the purpose of using Next.js after all

Comment: No, I don't. I think if you're committed to Next.js you're better off using Netlify or Zeit which are more geared to running Node.js apps, which Cloudflare Workers just aren't.

Comment: Gotchya, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mimic the response object like this.

```
        const page = require('./.next/serverless/pages/some_page.js');

        addEventListener('fetch', event => {
            event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
        })

        async function handleRequest(request) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                const response = {
                    setHeader: () => {},
                    getHeader: () => {},
                    end: (htmlString) => {
                        resolve(htmlString);
                    },
                };
                page.render(request, response);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out

Comment: @mrstack999 how'd you go?